# Nomenclature for mood, feelings and emotion in experimental-psychology

Tags: emotion, experimental-psychology, mood

I'm studying music therapy and music-based interventions relating to Substance Use Disorder.
[Music therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_therapy) and music-based interventions are increasingly used for the treatment of substance use disorder [(Hoffmann et al., 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5687713/)

I noticed that studies examining the effects of music therapy on mood, feeling and emotions of addicted patients use these three terms interchangeably. For example, [Jones (2005)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15913388/) refers to the terms
*"feeling and emotions"* (p.100) only to assess *"mood"* using a visual analogue scale.

**My question: Does a theory - or even a test (not necessarily about music-therapy experiments) -  handles those three terms (mood, feeling and emotions) as separate constructs?**

***P.S.** I aim to possibly differentiate these terms properly to implement an experiment*

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between affect and feeling?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16144/7001) and [What is the difference between emotions, intuition and affect?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17204/7001)